# React(JS) UI does not match state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a strange bug that I can't figure out for days, but I'm sure that is a problem that a React expert will detect in minutes.

the problem is - after removing dom element - the state show different thing from what I actually see.

see [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ryu-sdn-guixarrows-stackoverflow-hr97n).

the application is UI of boxes connected with arrows between them. you can remove or add arrows between boxes.

to recreate the issue: select box1 and select "Remove Connection", then, select box2.

you will see the arrow connected to box3 will be removed. what's strange your asking? look it the console - the state indicates you indeed removed the connection from box1 to box2 but the UI shows different things.

the remove function is in `./components/Box` line 38

what the problem is not:

1. this is not a problem with the arrows library. I've tried different libraries and exactly the same bug.
2. this is not a problem with the removal of this line from `lines`, as you can see with the consoled `lines` after removing.

I know this is not a small project with one file - but I'm really desperate and need help because I did not succeed in solving this by myself...

Comment: When I add a console.log to `getRefById` to check the `Id` that is passed, removing the line from box1 to box 2 outputs the correct messages but grabs the box with Id `box1`, then the one with Id `box3`.

Comment: `getRefById ` is not relevant. please see again the codesandbox - I've removed all irrelevant code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 97 of App.tsx you set the key from the index of your arrow Array , you need to put something else like this :

```
        <Xarrow
          //key={index} // From this 
          key={line.from+line.to} // to this (or somethinf relevant) 
          start={getRefById(line.from)}
          end={getRefById(line.to)}
          curveness={0.8}
          consoleWarning={false}
        />
```

Otherwise, when removing an element of the array, the array will decreased in size and the key to be removed will not be the on you want, but the last in the array

This is actually on react recommandation : never use index of array  in key.

Comment: wow man! just thanks! i looked at the wrong places all this time!
thank you very much!

Comment: Btw my key can be wrong (imagine an arrow from 1 to 21 and on one from 12 to 1, they will have the same key). 

`key={line.from+ '-'+line.to}` Will be unique

Comment: you right - thanks for the note. unbelievable how this small thing messed my work. thanks again.